# Android: Listview's row height changes when clicking on the checkbox it contains

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, height, android-relativelayout

I got an activity that contains a single listview.
This listview displays a relativeLayout with a bitmap and a checkbox and when no bitmap is available, a text is displayed.

My problem is with rows that contains no bitmap. When I click on the checkbox, the height of the row changes (increase when checkbox is checked, de crease when unchecked)

activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/gradient_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/registrationCheckBox"
        android:filter="true" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/registrationCheckBox" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/registrationCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"      
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >
    </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity code

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        hideActionBar(); 

        // init the controls
        initControls();

        // populate the listView
        this.adapter = new RegistrationAdapter(this, refreshContent());     
        this.listView.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        this.listView.setItemsCanFocus(false); 
        this.listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        this.listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

...
                    }
            }
    );  

    }
```

Any idea on how to prevent my row height to change when clicking on the checkbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the important part of this code, and that is the Adapter code.

How are you handling switching between bitmap and text?

Comment: You're totally right!
The I just saw I was using 

banner.setVisibility(hide ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

to hide the banner rather than View.GONE...
Swithcing to View.GONE did the trick... thanks for the hint !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set the ImageView to a fixed height (tall enough to fit in any actual image), or provide a dummy invisible image when there is no real image to show.